# c++ как наследовать private переменную из базового в private секцию дочернего класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Допустим у меня есть `интерфейс А` и `класс B`, который наследуется от `А`. В классе `А` **есть переменные хранящие данные о файле**, а `B` загружает файл и **записывает эти данные**, они должны быть в `private`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при наследовании переменные из `А` были недоступны, но их можно было использовать в `B` ?

```
template <typename _T>
class A {
public:
    virtual void LoadFile(const char* FileName) = 0;

private:
    _T* m_DataPtr;
    int m_ID;
    const char* m_FileName;
};

class B : A<char> {
    using A<char>::m_FileName; // C2877 'A<char>::m_FileName' is not accessible from 'A<char>'
    using A<char>::m_DataPtr;  // C2877 'A<char>::m_DataPtr' is not accessible from 'A<char>'
    using A<char>::m_ID;       // C2877 'A<char>::m_ID' is not accessible from 'A<char>'
public:
    B() = default;
    ~B() {
        delete(m_DataPtr);  // Error C2248 'A<char>::m_DataPtr': cannot access private member declared in class 'A<char>'
        m_ID = 0;           // Error C2248 'A<char>::m_ID': cannot access private member declared in class 'A<char>'
    }

    void LoadFile(const char* FileName) {
        FILE* file = fopen(FileName, "r");

        m_FileName = FileName;         // Error C2248 'A<char>::m_FileName': cannot access private member declared in class 'A<char>'
        m_ID = 1;                      // Error C2248 'A<char>::m_ID': cannot access private member declared in class 'A<char>'
        m_DataPtr = new char[10];      // Error C2248 'A<char>::m_DataPtr': cannot access private member declared in class 'A<char>'
        fread(m_DataPtr, 1, 10, file); // Error C2248 'A<char>::m_DataPtr': cannot access private member declared in class 'A<char>'

        fclose(file)
    }
};
```

Comment: И по какой причине "они должны быть в private". Если данные будут в защищенной части, все вопросы отпадут. Спецификатор доступа protected как раз для этих целей и служит.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Видимо, важные причины для "*чтобы при наследовании переменные из А были недоступны*" - т.е. `protected` не годится..

Comment: @Harry, в данном случаи не вижу никакой причины.  Нет ничего особенного, специализированного в данном базовом  классе, чтобы запретить доступ к данным другим наследникам. В принципе нужно отвечать на конкретный вопрос, но, лично я, не вижу нужды подходить к данному вопросу таким образом

Comment: данные наследникам наоборот только им и должны быть доступны, мне надо чтобы их нельзя было изменить извне

Comment: Тогда @ARHovsepyan совершенно прав, а вы неверно поставили задачу (в условии - *при наследовании переменные из А были недоступны*, сейчас - *данные наследникам наоборот только им и должны быть доступны*). Вы уж определитесь, доступны или недоступны, а то пока что мы живем в рамках формальной логики с законом исключенного третьего :) При `protected` члены класса доступны только наследникам, но не извне.

Answer (score 1):

Объявить коасс B другом класса A.

В классе A написать:

```
friend class B;
```

Както так:

```
class B;

template <typename _T>
class A {

friend class B;

public:
```

Comment: это можно, но в моем коде это будет костылем, у меня там устроено так: есть уровни, модели, текстуры и тд, у них у всех общий интерфейс IResource, по этому если сделать через friend, то при добавлении нового типа ресурса, придется изменять интерфейс

Comment: Я почитал комментарии - вы же поменяли условие на ходу (или неверно поставили сначала). Я отвечал на самое первое условие.

Comment: я не менял условие,

Comment: я изначально это условие и имел в виду. В комментариях @ARHovsepyan был прав, мне нужен был protected для решения этой задачи

Comment: Вы пишете, чтобы "при наследовании переменные из А были недоступны" - но protected делает их доступными при наследовании! Значит, **protected противоречит поставленной задаче**. И вы еще пишете, что не меняли условия задачи? Если бы я знал, что при наследовании данные могут быть доступны - то я бы тоже советовал protected.